# PostgreSQL serial ID does NOT populate when omitting the value in INSERT statement

Tags: postgresql

I am trying to simply insert JSON data in to a PostgreSQL database. The first column is a serial ID primary key column. When I try to insert the data and omit the serial id value, the serial id value is populated with my first record instead of automatically populating itself.

Example:

```
CREATE TABLE test (
    id SERIAL PRIMARY KEY,
    prem_id text,
    name text)
```

Coming from JSON pipeline:

```
INSERT INTO test VALUES ('1001','Lucy');
INSERT INTO test VALUES ('1002','Johnny');
```

Table populates as follows:

```
id   | prem_id | name
1001 | Lucy    | null
1002 | Johnny  | null
```

If I directly insert from pgAdmin, then I get the same results as above. The only time it works properly is if I add the DEFAULT keyword to the INSERT statement. Just doesn't make sense... All documentation I have read says if you omit this, then it should automatically increment.

I also tried

```
CREATE TABLE test (
    id INT PRIMARY KEY GENERATED ALWAYS AS IDENTITY,
    ...)
```

But I am getting a syntax error "at or before GENERATED". I'm really stuck on this one.

Anyone else experience this issue or have any fixes for it?

Much appreciated!

Comment: Specify the target colums, otherwise postgres will use the given values in order. `INSERT INTO test (prem_id, name) VALUES ('1001', 'Lucy')`. https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-insert.html *"The target column names can be listed in any order. **If no list of column names is given at all, the default is all the columns of the table in their declared order; or the first N column names, if there are only N columns supplied by the VALUES clause or query**. The values supplied by the VALUES clause or query are associated with the explicit or implicit column list left-to-right."*

Comment: i.e. because you're not specifying the target columns postgres has no way of knowing which column you're omitting, you could just as well be trying to omit `perm_id` or the `name`... how then would you expect postgres to know that?

Comment: Thankyou @mkopriva, this makes total sense now that I think about it. Quick question - if I set the id as SERIAL, then I read it creates an INT in the background for it. How am I able to pass a string to an INT column without it throwing an error?

Comment: To correct my previous comment a little bit, `'1001'` is of type `unknown`, i.e. an "untyped string constant", which the query parser assumes can be converted to anything, and in this case the assumption is correct, however if you tried the insert with `'abc'` it would of course fail. And an implicit cast will *not* work when the source value is a typed `text`/`varchar`, in that case one has to use an explicit cast, or one could also, I think, create an implicit cast beforehand with `CREATE CAST ...`

Comment: https://github.com/postgres/postgres/blob/1cff1b95ab6ddae32faa3efe0d95a820dbfdc164/src/backend/parser/parse_coerce.c#L572-L577

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to specify the target columns, otherwise the values are matched in the order the columns were defined in the CREATE TABLE statement. You also missed the `VALUES` clause:

```
INSERT INTO test 
  (prem_id, name)
values 
  ('1001','Lucy'),
  ('1002','Johnny');
```

[Online example](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_12&fiddle=c8b94c6b630156f5be0f5f4572e92049)